# Parallellizing, joining and error checking bash commands?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Consider the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

foo
bar
baz

fini
```

This will execute the subcommands `foo`, `bar` and `baz` one after the other in serial, and terminate if any one them fail (`set -e`), then it will execute the `fini` command.

How can I modify this script such that:

- the three subcommands `foo`, `bar` and `baz` are executed in parallel
- if any one of them fails (non-success exitcode) the script terminates (like `set -e`) and any running subcommands are terminated/waited on.
- the `fini` command is not run if and until all three `foo`, `bar` and `baz` have completed ( and have completed successfully)

Comment: Forced to terminate or waited to terminate normally?

Comment: @oguzismail: Waited to terminate normally is fine - although I'm sure an answer illustrating both cases would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Using [job control](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control.html) builtins like `wait` and `kill` on processes that run in the background.

Proof of concept example:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Starting jobs."

sleep 1 && echo "job 1" && exit 0 &
sleep 2 && echo "job 2 (Will fail)" && exit 1 &
sleep 3 && echo "job 3" && exit 0 &

echo "Waiting for jobs"

for ((n = 0; n < 3; n++)); do
    if ! wait -n; then
        echo "A job failed! Goodbye."
        while read pid; do
            kill $pid 2>/dev/null
        done < <(jobs -p)
        exit 1
    fi
done

echo "One last task"
```